# Open a file chooser within a django admin action

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to create an action on the django admin interface that allows a file to be selected and opened, then processed (with the end result of this processing to be saved down). I didn't know how to do this within an admin action, so I worked around it by adding an optional file field onto the model that the action is associated with, but this seems clumsy and wasteful.

How would I go about prompting the user to select a file after clicking on an admin action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create form

```
class SelectFileForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Add this code to your admin.py:

```
def select_file_action(modeladmin, request, queryset):
       form = None

       if 'apply' in request.POST:
           form = ChooseFileForm(request.POST)

           if form.is_valid():
               file = form.cleaned_data['file']

               count = 0
               for item in queryset:
                   #do something with file
                   item.file = file
                   item.save()
                   count += 1

               modeladmin.message_user(request, "File successfully selected")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

       if not form:
           form = SelectFileForm(initial={'_selected_action': request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)})

       return render(request, 'select_file.html', {'items': queryset,'form': form, 'title':'File'})

select_file_action.short_description = "Choose file"
```

Register your action

```
actions = [select_file_action,]
```

And select_file template:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

    <ul>{{ items|unordered_list }}</ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="select_file_action" />
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Save" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```